# Scrabble array in java

Tags: java, arrays, java.util.scanner, scrabble

So for a class, I need to make a program that scores a word based off of scrabble values for a letter. So `aa` should be `2` since 1 `a` is worth 1 point. But for some reason, my program only shows aa as 1 point.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Scrabble {   
       public static void main(String[] args) {
            String[] alphabet = {"a", "b", "c", "d", "e",  
               "f", "g", "h", "i",
               "j",   "k", "l", "m", "n", "o", 
               "p", "q", "r", "s", "t",   "u", "v",
               "w", "x", "y", "z"};

            int[] values = {1, 3, 3, 2, 1, 4,  
               2, 4, 1, 8, 5, 1, 3, 1, 1, 3, 10,
               1, 1, 1, 1, 4, 4, 8, 4, 10};

            Scanner kboard = new Scanner(System.in);
            System.out.println("Input your word.");

            String choice = kboard.nextLine();

            int score = 0;
            for(int i = 0; i < choice.length(); i++) {
                for(int n = 0; n < 26; n++)   {
                    if(choice.substring(i).equals(alphabet[n]))
                    {
                       score += values[n];
                    }
                }
             }

             System.out.println("The score for your word is " + score);
       }

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that `someStr.substring(i)` doesn't return only a single letter. For example, the output of `System.out.println("aaa".substring(1));` is `"aa"`, *not* `a`.

Here's a modified version:

```
char[] alphabet = {'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z'}; 
int[] values = {1, 3, 3, 2, 1, 4, 2, 4, 1, 8, 5, 1, 3, 1, 1, 3, 10, 1, 1, 1, 1, 4, 4, 8, 4, 10};
Scanner kboard = new Scanner(System.in); System.out.println("Input your word.");
String choice = kboard.nextLine();
int score = 0;
for(int i = 0; i < choice.length(); i++) {
  for(int n = 0; n < 26; n++) {
    // Use charAt here instead of substring
    if(choice.charAt(i) == alphabet[n])
    {
      score += values[n];
    }
  }
}
System.out.println("The score for your word is " + score);
```

}

Even better, you could just use a Hash Table for the alphabet and avoid the inner loop.

Comment: Im stupid guys sorry i forgot that you had to enter a second variable in the subtring.

Comment: @IsaiahMitchell It's actually a really easy mistake to make.

Comment: Actually, you can cast char to int (fix offsets) and skip the map too!

Comment: @Tezra That's true, you can.

Answer (score 0):

Because "aa".substring(0) == "aa" which != "a". So basically this is an expensive 'score last char'.

Use choice.charAt(index) instead. (also, you could just us a char to map lookup to skip iterating over every char)

Answer (score 0):

You're using the wrong version of the substring, I'd assume you wanted to use [substring(int beginIndex, int endIndex)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#substring(int,%20int))

This version of substring should enable you to select only *one* character substring to compare against your alphabets array. However, when using [substring(int beginIndex)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#substring(int)) the substring begins with the character at the specified index and extends to the end of this string, meaning you're selecting more than *one* character substring (except when you're at `alphabet.length-1` ).

Alternatively to solve the problem at hand, simply change your `if` condition to this:

```
if(Character.toString(choice.charAt(i)).equals(alphabet[n]))
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this solution:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Scrabble {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String[] alphabet = {"a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i", "j", "k", "l", "m", "n", "o", "p", "q", "r", "s", "t", "u", "v", "w", "x", "y", "z"};
        int[] values = {1, 3, 3, 2, 1, 4, 2, 4, 1, 8, 5, 1, 3, 1, 1, 3, 10, 1, 1, 1, 1, 4, 4, 8, 4, 10};

        Scanner kboard = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Input your word.");
        String choice = kboard.nextLine();

        int score = 0;
        for(int i = 0; i < choice.length(); i++) {
            for(int n = 0; n < 26; n++) {
                if(choice.substring(i, i + 1).equals(alphabet[n])) {
                    score += values[n];
                }
            }
        }

        System.out.println("The score for your word is " + score);
    }
}
```

Basically, you are not using [substring()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#substring-int-int-) correctly. You only entered a begin index, which means that it reads from that point until the end of the string. I changed it to read to the end index, which in your case is `i+1`.

Basically in you first iteration you were looking for "aa" in `alphabet` and only in your second iteration were you looking for only "a" in `alphabet`, which is why you didn't get your first '1 point' in the first iteration.